# How can I substitute a variable in format command of python?

Tags: python, format

My code finds an unknown (0<alpha<1), its precision depends on another parameter (dm). Finally, alpha is determined with e.g. 20 digits but depending on dm, alpha should be kept until definite (which is known during execution=njj) digit. At the end, I need to substitute njj in format command as following:

njj= 8 ;alpha= 0.0004258819580078126 # I need this alpha= 0.00042588

print('{:.njj f}'.format(alpha))

But it doesn't work!

It shows:
ValueError: Format specifier missing precision

Comment: You can use the round function: 
    
    print(round(alpha, njj))

OUTPUT:

    0.00042588

Comment: Be aware that if you're using standard Python `float`s, you can't get 20 digits of precision.  You'll get 16, maybe 17.

Comment: i can't get it to work with format function. but this works: `print(f'{alpha:.{njj}f}')`

Comment: i found out how to make it work with format and forgot to post it: `format(alpha, f'.{njj}f')`. there's some weird mechanic i can't understand

Comment: @diggusbickus, Great job! would you please tell me your reference? I spent hours to find this but there was nothing helpful!

Comment: docs for [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) (and i just discovered the notation `{nij=}`, what a banger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is quite a good question.

i find that this works nicely:

```py
njj= 8
alpha= 0.0004258819580078126 # I need this alpha= 0.00042588

print(f'{alpha:.{njj}f}')
```

which gives this:

```
0.00042588
```

but also, you could do this:

```py
print(round(alpha, njj))
```

**update**:
As per the comments below from @Mark, the `round()` function produces *a different number of decimal places* compared to the formatted `f-string` method when there are trailing Zero's. So the user would need to decide which one they wanted to see.

Comment: Your two answers are not the same when you have trailing zeros.

Comment: @MarkRansom,  how do you mean the answers are not the same with _"trailing zeros"_ ?   if `alpha= 0.0004258819580078126` is changed to `alpha= 0.00042588000` it gives the same answer.  Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Try `alpha= 0.00042580000`.  I get `0.00042580` and `0.0004258`.

Comment: @MarkRansom,  thank you for pointing this out.  I have included this as an update to the answer. Good spot !